# Titanium Push notification "events" is not working (android)

Tags: android, titanium, google-cloud-messaging, push

Registration id is giving but event is not triggered. I don't understand why?

Please Help me. I did not understand where wrong?

```
// Cloud module and Cloud module use
        Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

        var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
            backgroundColor : '#ccc',
            title : 'Android Cloud Push Notification'
        });

        //CloudPush modules variables
        var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
        CloudPush.debug = true;
        CloudPush.enabled = true;
        CloudPush.showTrayNotification = true;
        CloudPush.showTrayNotificationsWhenFocused = true;
        CloudPush.focusAppOnPush = false;

        //Device Token variables
        var deviceToken;
        var Cloud = require('ti.cloud');
        Cloud.debug = true;

        //create button
        var submit = Ti.UI.createButton({
            title : 'Register For Push Notification',
            color : '#000',
            height : 53,
            width : 200,
            top : 100,
        });

        //add button on win scene
        win.add(submit);

        //CloudPush retrieveDeviceToken function
        submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
                success : function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
                    alert('======= Device Token: ' + e.deviceToken);
                    deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
                    loginDefault();
                },
                error : function deviceTokenError(e) {
                    alert('======= Failed to register for push! ' + e.error);
                }
            });
        });            

        //Cloud login
        function loginDefault(e) {
            // At first you need to create an user from the application dashboard
            // Then login that email and password
            Cloud.Users.login({
                login : '===',
                password : '==='
            }, function(e) {
                if (e.success) {
                    alert("========login success");
                    defaultSubscribe();
                } else {
                    alert('Error: ' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
                }
            });
        }

        function defaultSubscribe() {
            Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribe({
                channel : 'alert',
                device_token : deviceToken,
                type : 'android'
            }, function(e) {
                if (e.success) {
                    alert('====== Subscribed for Push Notification!');
                } else {
                    alert('Error:' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
                }
            });
        }

         //Doesnt Work this events
        CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function(evt) {
            console.log(evt);
            console.log(evt.payload);
        });

        //Doesnt Work this events
        CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickLaunchedApp', function(evt) {
            console.log('Tray Click Launched App (app was not running)');
            //alert('Tray Click Launched App (app was not running');
        });

        //Doesnt Work trayClickFocusedApp  events
        CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickFocusedApp', function(evt) {
            console.log('Tray Click Focused App (app was already running)');
            //alert('Tray Click Focused App (app was already running)');
        });

        win.open();
```

Comment: Could you be more specific and explain "Registration id is giving but event is not triggered." ?

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen  i recruiting device token with this code and I can at the push notification. And then i add push notification event But if i clicking on the event push notification event doesn't trigger. And I don't understand where is the problem.

I use senderId and gcm API key
What can i do?

Comment: I don't get "But if i clicking on the event push notification event doesn't trigger"